# I dont know why print("Accuracia:", score) isnt work

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm doing an artificial intelligence work on pattern recognition (whether the animals are bats or not)

my classifier is neural network

so my code is like this right now:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Loading data from Names.txt and Wpc50.dat file
data = pd.read_csv("Wpc50.dat", sep='\s+', header=None, dtype=float)
species = pd.read_csv("Names.txt", header=None, names=["species"])


# Splitting the data into training and testing, 75% for training and 25% for testing.
data_train, data_test, species_train, species_test = train_test_split(data, species, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

#Scaling of training data
scaler = StandardScaler()
data_train_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(data_train)

# Applying the same transformations on the test data
data_test_normalized = scaler.transform(data_test)

# Encoding of the Names.txt file, the names are in string and I need to transform them to numerical data
encoder = LabelEncoder()
species_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(species.values.ravel())
species_train, species_test, species_train_encoded, species_test_encoded = train_test_split(species, species_encoded, random_state=0)

species_train_encoded = encoder.transform(species_train.values.ravel())
encoder.handle_unknown = 'ignore'
species_test_encoded = encoder.transform(species_test.values.ravel())

# Creating the neural network
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), max_iter=1000, random_state=0)

# Training the neural network
mlp.fit(data_train_normalized, species_train_encoded)

# Evaluating the model
score = mlp.score(data_test_normalized, species_test_encoded)
print("Accuracy:", score)
```

anyway, in my terminal no errors appear, but the print() does not work
someone can help me please?
its my homework from college
maybe is the neural network, i'll try some less complicated

Comment: What does it means "does not work"? What happens? Does it prints nothing, does it prints "Accuracy:" with nothing afterwards...?

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "does not work" is not a description of a problem, and "someone can help me please?" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: why u gringos are so mean i just asked a question

Answer (score 0):

there are couple things you need to fix there. First of all, you are making mistake on preprocessing. `encoder.fit_transform` transforms the data so you dont need to do it again
following lanes are unnecerry

```
species_train_encoded = encoder.transform(species_train.values.ravel())
encoder.handle_unknown = 'ignore'
species_test_encoded = encoder.transform(species_test.values.ravel())
```

secondly, there is a bug on spliting the data. You split it on the top and than you split the labels again and fit not matching values to your network. (It shouldnt be working but idk) I recommend moving the following lane and deleting the other stuff.

```
# Splitting the data into training and testing, 75% for training and 25% for testing.
data_train, data_test, species_train, species_test = train_test_split(data, species, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
```

So end result would be something like following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Loading data from Names.txt and Wpc50.dat file
data = pd.read_csv("Wpc50.dat", sep='\s+', header=None, dtype=float)
species = pd.read_csv("Names.txt", header=None, names=["species"])

#Scaling of training data
scaler = StandardScaler()
data_train_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(data)

# Encoding of the Names.txt file, the names are in string and I need to transform them to numerical data
encoder = LabelEncoder()
species_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(species.values.ravel())


# Splitting the data into training and testing, 75% for training and 25% for testing.
data_train, data_test, species_train, species_test = train_test_split(data_train_normalized ,species_encoded , test_size=0.25, random_state=0)


# Creating the neural network
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), max_iter=1000, random_state=0)

# Training the neural network
mlp.fit(data_train, species_train)

# Evaluating the model
score = mlp.score(data_test, species_test )
print("Accuracy:", score)
```

Comment: if you want to use neural networks, I reccommend using keras or tf. but if you are begginer I think its better if you start learning from logistic regression, decision trees and SVM. try to get good foundation on those before you get into neural networks. MLP relatively easy but not helpfull in every stiation.